# Second Activity Screen doesn't display the layout defined in secondscreen.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am new here, and new to Android Programming as well. So any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

I am running an Android App(basically the example given in developer.android.com) and customizing it, to add a navigation bar at the top which displays the screen number. The idea of the app is to let the user enter a message in the 1st screen, and display the message in the second screen. I've been able to setup a navigation bar in the 1st screen which displays(1/2), and have similarly defined a layout in the second screen's xml file which should display the navigation bar and (2/2) in it. Also, I have added a "Stop" button, which I will make use of later.

However, the problem I am facing is- the second screen displays only the message received from the user, and not the layout I want(navigation bar). I think I have correctly determined the root cause of this, to be the below code:

```
//Create the text view 
TextView textView = new TextView(this); 
textView.setTextSize(40); 
textView.setText(message); 

// Set the text view as the activity layout
setContentView(textView);
```

I think the setContentView() method that I've used here is displaying the message I received from the 1st activity. When I comment out this line, I get my desired formatting of the second screen by using:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);
```

However, I am not able to understand fully why and how to club both the things together. It looks like the setContentView(R.layout..) doesn't work as expected when the setContentView(textView) is not commented, which is I guess, normal.

Thank You in advance.

Edit- Thank You, CodeMagic for such a prompt response. Before I try out your solution, here's the complete on create. I have some code in there which deals with a "stop" button, but am yet to implement it. So please ignore that.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);//Change-11/10 6:00 PM


Button buttonStop=(Button)findByViewId(R.id.buttonStop);//Change-11/10 6:00 PM
buttonStop.setOnClickListener(stopListener);//Change-11/10 6:00 PM

Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(FirstActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);

// Create the text view - this code prints the message typed in first
//screen and displays on second screen, ignoring the xml layout of second screen     
TextView textView = new TextView(this); 
textView.setTextSize(40); 
textView.setText(message); 

// Set the text view as the activity layout
setContentView(textView); //change-11/11-9:00 PM
//setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete `onCreate()` of your second `Activity`? I think I know what the problem is but hard to tell with these pieces

Comment: Or see my answer. I think this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to just add the `TextView` to your `activity_second_screen.xml` before runtime. Then in your `onCreate()` you can just add the `message` as it seems you are getting that correctly even though its not shown. So do something like

```
EditText et;

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
     super.onCreate(bundle);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);
     et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextID); // where editTextId is 
                                                    //the id you give the 
                                                   //EditText in your layout file
     et.setText(message); //this will be done after you get your message variable
                          // I assume through an Intent
}
```

then you don't need

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this); 
textView.setTextSize(40);
```

When you call `setContentView()` more than once each time it sets the `View` to whatever is in `setContentView()` and overwrites whatever was previously called in `setContentView()`

Answer (score 0):

You can  message from first screen by using `intent.putExtra(key,value)` and get this message in second screen by using `intent.getExtra(key)` this will return the value you have send in first activity and will get this and display where ever you want in your second screen

In first activity next button use below code

Intent i = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
    i.putExtra("key", "value");
    startActivity(i);

In the second activity onCreate method write below code snippet

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String ans = extras.getString("key");
```